# Simple Simulation: Fast Forward and Normal Timer

Tags: c#, timer, simulation

A simple draw and move simulation uses the following:

**A clock timer**. Interval: *200ms*.
**A movement timer**. Interval: *1ms*.
**Movement Constant.** Value: *2.*

Every time the **movement timer** ticks, a picture moves by addition by the movement constant. (i.e. picture.X = picture.X + movement constant)

The problem is **fast forwarding**. The user CAN fast-forward the simulation at any time.

How do I change theses three values (clock timer, movement timer, movement constant) to make the simulation speed faster without sacrificing integrity during a fast-forwarded run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If integer multiples (1x, 2x, 3x, ...) for fast forwarding is enough, you could just run the simulation function several times during the timer handler function.

I'm not sure what you're doing with the clock timer though, but the same principle would apply to whatever it's doing.

Comment: The clock timer runs a clock which in turn would evaluate when a picture should arrive. That's why I'm worried the sim wouldn't be the same when fast forwarding. Also, I can't speed up my clock timer since it's the lowest: 1ms. What value should I change my movement constant to?

Comment: You don't need to speed up the timers if you just run the simulation functions several times: instead of `picture.X += movementConstant;` you'd do `for(int i = 0; i < speedFactor; i++) picture.X += movementConstant;`. (I'm assuming your simulation function is a little more complex though in reality :))

Comment: Yes, I put up a super-ultra-hyper-simplified version just for the purpose of asking. I'll try your suggestion, haven't thought of that. I hope the extra for-loops isn't too much because the sim computes a lot of data. Thank you.

Edit: It appears to be working but the timing inconsistencies exists esp. for  larger multiples. (4x, 5x...) I'll do an in-depth test.

Answer (score 1):

You can have an "internal time" that's independant of the "real time". When the system runs at the base speed, these two increase in sync (every tick of the timer - that's set to 1 ms - adds 1ms to the internal time.
When you have a speedup multiplier of 2x, then add 2ms to the internal time for every timer tick.

Next you will have to calculate positions based on the internal time, with maybe a function like

```
newposition = startposition + speed * time
```

Answer (score 1):

As Hans implied, there is a 'grain-size' in time and space in most simulations. Agents are then scheduled by skipping over time intervals ('ticks'). However, if you need more flexible and well-tested scheduling, you might want to borrow a scheduler from an ABM simulation package such as Mason (for Java) or Repast (Java or C++), or look at their open-source scheduler class codes and translate to another language.